# setRoot not working on getActiveNavs/getRootNavById

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I have a method `changeView()` where I check certain authentications and permissions.

Here below the method:

```
changeView () : void {
    let navCtrl: NavController = this.app.getActiveNavs()[0];
    let hasFetchedDashboardPermission: boolean = this.permissionService.hasFetchedMenuPermission(PermissionId.PAGE_HOME);
    // let testNav;

        console.log(this.globalService.isAuthenticated(), !hasFetchedDashboardPermission, navCtrl.getActive() !== undefined)
        if(navCtrl.getActive() !== undefined){
            console.log('active navCtrl', navCtrl.getActive().id)
        }

        if (this.globalService.isAuthenticated() && hasFetchedDashboardPermission 
                && navCtrl.getActive() !== undefined && navCtrl.getActive().id !== 'home' && navCtrl.getActive().id !== 'collegekaart') {
            console.log('setHome');

            navCtrl.setRoot('home');
        } else if (this.globalService.isAuthenticated() && !hasFetchedDashboardPermission
                    && navCtrl.getActive() !== undefined && navCtrl.getActive().id !== 'login') {

            this.globalService.deleteApiSecurityParams();

            console.log('check1', navCtrl.isTransitioning());
            let test = this.app.getActiveNavs();
            test[0].setRoot('login');

            this.testNav = this.app.getRootNavById('n4');
            this.testNav.setRoot('login');

            // this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('login');

            //navCtrl.setRoot('login', null, null, () => { console.log('onDane') })
            // navCtrl.setRoot('login');
        }
    }
```

As you see I tried a couple of things but all of these are not working.. I really don't know why it is not firing the setRoot method at all!!

Answer (score 0):

What is your console output? Which log are/aren't displayed ?

Why don't you use the dependency injection with your NavController instead of retrieving it via the `this.app.getActiveNavs()[0]` instruction ?

Try adding it directly in your component constructor like this :

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class ItemDetailsPage {

    constructor(navCtrl: NavController) {}

    changeView () : void {

        ... 

        if(this.navCtrl.getActive() !== undefined){
            console.log('active navCtrl', this.navCtrl.getActive().id)
        }

        ...
    }
}
```